# How to hide the 'Press F1 for more help' in AutoCAD ribbon?

Tags: tooltip, ribbon, autocad

How to **hide** the text 'Press F1 for more help' but keep the tooltip above it ? Even though we press F1 for more help, a help window will be popped-up and search from the official document with no result, therefore such help shortcut can be removed here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new tooltip and assign to the button

Comment: Can you explain more detail ? In fact, the text can be hidden using c# code, but I don't know if it is possible to do it using the command `cui` in AutoCAD.